# Field strength tensor from covariant derivative

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-theory

The field strength tensor in a local abelian gauge theory is defined as:

$$ F_{\mu\nu}=[D_\mu,D_\nu] ~~(*)$$

where

$$D_{\mu}=\partial_\mu-ieA_\mu$$

when I insert this into $(*)$ I get:

$$(\partial_\mu-ieA_\mu)(\partial_\nu-ieA_\nu)-(\partial_\nu-ieA_\nu)(\partial_\mu-ieA_\mu)=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu +A_\mu \partial_\nu -A_\nu \partial_\mu$$

The last two terms are too much. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commutator of covariant derivative and field $F_{\mu \nu}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/592196/)

Comment: You need to think of the derivatives on the LHS acting on a function.